# Does postgres automatically change record ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm relying on the `id` field of postgresql records not changing in a rails app. Certain tests have indicated that postgres might be changing the ids of some of the records. Does postgres do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases do not manipulate their own data - they always require someone to execute an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.  That someone could be an automated job...

Weird data means that you aren't selecting what you thought you were, or bad data was allowed to be inserted.  Post your query, sample data and the expected result for us to review what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't be a reliable database when it changes data on it's own.