# Automatic modification of IDs in Django on deletion of instances

Tags: django, django-models

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402936/does-postgres-automatically-change-record-ids), so perhaps it's Django's behavior that I'm not understanding, or perhaps I changed something myself without realizing it, but, after deleting several instances of a table (perhaps I deleted the parent instance and ON DELETE CASCADE occurred), I found that the automatically-generated IDs of other instances in that table had changed. I believe that I'd called .delete() on the models. Would Django ever do this? The database was Postgres.

Comment: Django (or anybody, in their own sanity) doesn't change the IDs of already-existing records. Of course, new records will continue the ID enumeration from where it stopped, and the ones that were deleted are not replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no evidence that this was the case, but I'll guess that human error was involved in order to close the question.